# flexbox not working in safari 5.1 windows

Tags: windows, css, safari, flexbox

I am new to CSS, Flexbox and Frontend development. I wanted to build a site with Flexbox, CSS3 and HTML5. (No Frameworks)

Safari 5.1 for Windows does not work with Flexbox . 
I played with Chris Coyier's "Old and New Browser Comparability" solution and it worked but seems limited.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to build a second stylesheet specifically for Safari?
2. How do I integrate styling without messing up the "Coyier" Structure CSS in my Safari stylesheet?
3. How can I get the Safari browser to ignore the stylesheet created for other browsers?
4. Can you suggest reading, site examples or what you did to address this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: According to CanIUse.com it doesn't look like there is full support of Safari 5 with flex.  (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)   You should be able to get specific with the styling whether it's using prefixes, referring to on page styling or another stylesheet.  Would you mind posting some code of a link to a jsfiddle to better understand your situation?

Answer (score 4):

Safari for Windows was available from 2007 to 2012 before it was discontinued. As it hasn't been updated in five years, it doesn't support many modern web standards - and as such, virtually nobody is using it. You shouldn't need to test against it for compatibility.

More information:

- http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/25/apple_kills_windows_pc_support_in_safari_60
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)

Comment: @JonUleis I went slightly mental trying to fix flexbox issues -- Glad its dead